# How to fix issue Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.next/server/package.json' in next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

After updating my application from next.js 12 to 13 while running `npm run dev`  I am getting this issue
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.next/server/package.json'. How to resolve this? Do I need to configure anything extra for this?